# resttemplate put is working for only 20 rows, the rest rows are ignored?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, psql, resttemplate

I am facing this weird issue in my spring boot app which uses psql and hibernate.

When this app runs very first time it updates only 20 rows. However when I run it again after killing it it updates all 22 rows. And also if I update manually the other rows then psql is getting updated for these rows as well.

below is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.PUT,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void add(@RequestBody UserView userView) {
         userViewService.add(userView);
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/getalluser",method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public List<UserView> getAllUser() {
        System.out.println("no: of user:.........."+userViewService.getAlluserDetails().size());
        return userViewService.getAlluserDetails();
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults= false
```

resttemplate:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonRequest = om.writeValueAsString(userView);

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonRequest, httpHeaders);
        System.out.println("...................."+jsonRequest);
        restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/add", entity);
```

model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userview")
public class UserView {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userId;
```

What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.